# Can not get OptionValue with SetDelayed variable

Tags: functions, function-construction, pattern-matching, options

```
ClearAll[foo1];
foo1[OptionsPattern[]] := Hold[OptionValue[""]][[1, 1]]
foo1[]
```

gives function name

```
foo1
```

But

```
ClearAll[getName];
getName := Hold[OptionValue[""]][[1, 1]]
ClearAll[foo2];
foo2[OptionsPattern[]] := getName;
foo2[]
```

get nothing. Why? How to modify the definition of `getName` to make it work?

Comment: Essentially the same problem, I believe (you can read Chinese, right?): https://note.youdao.com/ynoteshare/index.html?id=a9c14381c11b44ad47980c44c200d529&type=note&_time=1689499410960

Comment: @xzczd Thank you so much! A tough read for my limited understanding : ). So do you mean `OptionValue` must be explicitly visible to the main function? Sorry, I still do not know how to write `getName`.

Comment: Yeah, that's what I mean, so I believe there's no way to define a `getName` that works as expected. `Hold@(foo2[OptionsPattern[]] := getName) /. OwnValues@getName // ReleaseHold` will work, though. Is this work-around of interest?

Comment: @xzczd That would be too cumbersome : )

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As mentioned in the comment above, I believe it's not possible because the `OptionValue` won't **explicitly exist** at the right hand side of the function if it's stored in the variable `getName`. However, we can achieve something very similar with `$Pre`:

```
ClearAll[$Pre, "getName", foo2];
$Pre = Function[a, Unevaluated@a /. getName :> Hold[OptionValue[""]][[1, 1]], 
   HoldAll];
foo2[OptionsPattern[]] := getName;
foo2[]
(* foo2 *)
```

Personally I think setting `$Pre` isn't that flexible, and defining a helper function is better:

```
help = 
  Function[a, Unevaluated@a /. getName :> Hold[OptionValue[""]][[1, 1]], HoldAll];
foo2[OptionsPattern[]] := getName; // help
foo2[]
(* foo2 *)
```

You need to type an extra `// help`, but I think this is acceptable?

Comment: Thank you so much!